# Error causing elements of a list when looping / iterating in Python script

Tags: list, loops

I am running a script in a loop for each element of a list. If some elements cause an error, how to print a list of error-causing elements in the end after all the elements are looped through?

##### For example:

```py
f=["ABC","PQR","UVW","XYZ"]

for f in f:
  try:
    'blah blah'
  except:
    continue 

# print("Error causing elements are " ..........
```

Comment: I am not able to test and hence know which of the reply solves my query as I get 'Connection closed' response when an element causes error. I am using my code to get data from web. Thanks everybody for reply.

Comment: You should provide more specified information.

Answer (score 3):

#### Before getting started

I changed variable `f` in the for each loop to `element` for not getting confused and also I wrote a `foo` function that throws an exception randomly.

#### Solution

You can add the error-causing elements to a list in the main loop like this: (you have access to the error-causing element in the `except:` block by variable `element` in each loop)

```py
f=["ABC","PQR","UVW","XYZ"]
error_elements = []

def foo(element):
    from random import randint
    if randint(0, 1) > 0:
        raise Exception()

for element in f:
    try:
        foo(element)
    except:
        error_elements.append(element)

print("Error causing elements are ", error_elements)
```

#### Another Option

Or if you throw the exception, there's another option that you can use and pass the error-causing element and anything else to the `Exception` function call and access them in `except` block by catching the `Exception` like `except Exception as e`

```py
f=["ABC","PQR","UVW","XYZ"]
error_elements = []

def foo(element):
    from random import randint
    if randint(0, 1) > 0:
        raise Exception('blah blah', element)

for element in f:
    try:
        foo(element)
    except Exception as e:
        # print('Error message is:', e.args[0])
        error_elements.append(e.args[1])

print("Error causing elements are ", error_elements)
```

Comment: I think the first option is better as it is less prune to changes in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Matin's answer is good. However if you have a list containing the same element multiple times you might want to use a set instead to keep your error message shorter:

```py
f=["ABC","PQR","UVW","XYZ"]
errors=set()

for f in f:
  try:
    'blah blah'
  except:
    errors.add(f)
    continue 

# print(f"Error causing elements are {errors}" ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
try:  
    'your code'
except Exception as e: 
    print(f'The error was " {e} "')
else:
    print("No errors")
```

Tell me that if this works!